# Erase of a Log Analytics Workspace in use, its recomended?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

We are redesigning how we using our LAW and i was wondering if we can delete LAW that are being being used. In this specific scenario, i noticed that while i could disconect some virtual machines, when I do try to disconect AKS resources, well.. it doesnt seems to be possible.

[image]

Currently, we have tons of dev related resources that we want to clean it up, but since it seems to be in use, im not finding any information that i could rely on making sure that i can safely delete some of Log Analytics Workspaces.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the logs are being logged into Azure Log Analytics, yes, you can delete the Log Analytics Workspace. It has no negative effect.

Comment: Hi , thanks for you feedback on that, i could not find any official resource or documentation for that information, would you have any source of confirmation by any chance?

Comment: @thclpr, you can take a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/delete-workspace#considerations-when-deleting-a-workspace).

Comment: Thanks for you r time on this, I manage to confirm with an additional research and yes, your answer is correct m

Answer (score 0):

The Log Analytics Workspace will just house the diagnostic information, this should not be any impact to the resources attached to it.  Unless there are triggers hooked up in terms of scaling in/out based upon metrics.  If so then these rules will go with it as well.  Please not too that the default behavior is a [soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/delete-workspace).